# Parts of page are invisible when scrolling on Safari 7 with position:fixed elements

Tags: css, safari, ios7, mobile-safari

There's a pretty big bug in Safari 7 on both Mac and iOS that's hard to find anything on, but is pretty easy to fix.

In some situations when using position:fixed, Safari 7 fails to draw part of the page when scrolling. This can be seen at http://ruelculture.com/glitchy.html by clicking on the arrow, waiting a bit and trying to scroll back up.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To fix this, force hardware acceleration on the disappearing element by adding the following CSS hack:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

See it in the wild at http://ruelculture.com/. That's it!

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to share this fix! Do you think it's the same issue as http://java.dzone.com/articles/safaris-lazy-repaint-bug-ios-7 ?

Comment: Definitely seems likely that it's the same bug. This actually isn't the first time Safari's had a big failing-to-paint issue: in Mac Safari, there were issues for years where Safari would "forget" to repaint big squares of the canvas when using an integrated graphics chip.

Answer (score 0):

There is also `position:-webkit-sticky;`, which is made specifically for this problem. I've had mixed results with my answer and @Mike Marcacci's solution (flickering, elements disappearing when you reach the bottom of the page). I'm still trying to find the perfect solution to this problem. [HTML5 Rocks =>](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit)